# .NET: Properties.Settings backend using the registry as storage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've had cases of my .NET WinForms app crashing in the wild at startup when I try to access a member of Properties.Settings.Default. After some investigation I found out it happens when you have an empty or corrupted (full of '\0' characters) user.config (at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Company Name\ExeName_hash?\Version\user.config`). This happens extremely early, in the Program class constructor, so I haven't found a way to detect it and fix it.

So I'm thinking of moving my settings to the registry, if only because it doesn't get corrupted that easily. Has anybody written a replacement backend for Properties.Settings that stores them in the Registry? Can anybody give me pointers as to how I would go around doing it?

Comment: Registry keys can get corrupted just as easily as files.  Not in the least because they are stored in a file :)  Google "registrysettingsprovider sample".

Comment: Why not spend time investigating how the file gets corrupted in the first place? Maybe whatever is doing it would be equally poisonous with the registry.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever had it happen to me once when the power went off suddenly.